# Concretely, what are the advantages of using DroneIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, drone.io

I'm a newbie on DroneIO and I'm wondering, concretely, what are the advantages of using it ? I know there is some pipeline automation but I can't grab the real benefit of using it, concretely why is a great thing or benefiting choice to use DroneIO please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, very personal reasons:

- "clean build" out of the box
- simple to use plugin system
- job definition as part of the code